# on qutip is it possible to transform a state to vector?

Tags: python, quantum-computing, qutip

If I build a state

```
from qutip import Bloch,basis
state=(basis(2,0)+(0+1j)*basis(2,1)).unit()
```

can I trasform it in ***a bloch-sphere vector***?

In this form:

```
state -> vec=np.array
```

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to convert a 2dvector in C(2) into a vector in R(3) living inside the bloch-sphere using this code:

```
from qutip.operators import sigmax, sigmay, sigmaz

def extract_vec(v):
    v=[v]
    vector=[]
    for i in v:
        vector.append([
            expect(sigmax(),i),
            expect(sigmay(),i),
            expect(sigmaz(),i)     
        ])
    return(vector)

3d_vec=extract_vec(state)
```

Comment: What is the expect() function? Also, `3d_vec` is not a proper Python syntax...